# Where did Maports change my $PATH in mac?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, macports, path-variables

I think the only way for macports to set $PATH is through ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile. I have checked that I don't have ~/.bashrc. But after comment out line:

```
 #export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

I still got /opt/local/bin in my $PATH

```
$echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin
```

I am wondering where else macport has changed my PATH variable, and it should be after loading ~/.bash_profile, because I add texlive path to the beginning of the path in ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: Did you quit and restart terminal?

Answer (score 0):

On OSX the sequence of files executed when you start an interactive bash terminal are as follows:

```
/etc/profile
/etc/bashrc
~/.bash_profile
```

It has to be one of those.  Looking at a comment left by [macports](http://www.macports.org) in my `.bash_profile` it is there.